# My address has been changed

Tags: wallet, address

Someone sent bitcoins to my address

```
1FGhx3FEJptmr4b8N68ceWbqHdTt7c4Ycz
```

But when I look at my address now, it has been changed to

```
1HEt95bb7ngshaQhUqi7LZVrJRxDRHu7ws
```

Will the bitcoins still arrive at the first address?

Comment: It would help if you told us what wallet you're using for us to assess what may have happened.

Comment: what wallet do you use?

Answer (score 2):

My guess, without knowing what exactly you did or which wallet you are using, is that you clicked again on the "receive bitcoin" button. Every time you do that a new address is created. This is for security/privacy reasons (you should not reuse addresses).

Anyways normally all addresses (actually their corresponding keys) created this way are automatically saved in your wallet so you should be good.